# Handle BackPress for Fragment in AndroidX FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a **MainActivity** in which I have implemented a drawer and a fragments. Now, I am adding and removing fragments from the stack using **ManageFragments** class mentioned below. I am able to replace fragments over one other but unable to pop fragments from stack after added to previous fragments on **Back Press**. Here is my implementation so far.

Here is what I am trying to implement:

DrawerItem1 -> Frag1 -> Frag2 -> Frag3 -> Frag4

DrawerItem2 -> Frag5

DrawerItem3 -> Frag6

DrawerItem4 -> Frag7

So, when user is in frag1 and presses Frag5. User should able to return to frag1.

Likewise, if user in navigates to frag4 than can navigate back to frag1 by **back press**

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have developed a common class where I can add and pop fragments in a single FragmentContainerView that's 'nav_host_fragment'

**ManageFragments.java**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ManageFragments {

public static String backStateName;
public static String fragmentTag;
public static FragmentManager manager;
public static boolean fragmentPopped;

public static void replaceFragment(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, Fragment fragment) {
    backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    fragmentTag = backStateName;
    manager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, fragmentTag);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

public static void popFragment(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    manager = Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentActivity).getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}

public static void clearFragments(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    manager = Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentActivity).getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (Fragment fragment : manager.getFragments()) {
        fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my implementation of **MainActivity.java**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavController navController;
private NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
private NavigationView navigationView;
public static Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

    navHostFragment =
            (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            navController.getGraph())
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_category, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   
    }
}
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.drawerapp.fragment.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_subCategoryFragment"
        app:destination="@id/subCategoryFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_enter" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/subCategoryFragment"
    android:name="com.drawerapp.fragment.sub_category.SubCategoryFragment"
    android:label="SubCategoryFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_subCategoryFragment_to_galleryFragment"
        app:destination="@id/galleryFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_enter" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_subCategoryFragment_to_nav_home"
        app:destination="@id/nav_home"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_exit" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/galleryFragment"
    android:name="com.drawerapp.fragment.gallery.GalleryFragment"
    android:label="GalleryFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_galleryFragment_to_subCategoryFragment"
        app:destination="@id/subCategoryFragment"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_exit" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_fav"
    android:name="com.drawerapp.fragment.favorites.FavoritesFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_fav"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorite">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_fav_to_nav_home"
        app:destination="@id/nav_home"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_exit" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
    android:name="com.drawerapp.fragment.feedback.FeedbackFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_feedback"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feedback">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_feedback_to_nav_fav"
        app:destination="@id/nav_fav"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_exit" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
    android:name="com.drawerapp.fragment.about_us.AboutUsFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_about_us"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about_us">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_about_us_to_nav_feedback"
        app:destination="@id/nav_feedback"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_exit" />
</fragment>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could u provide error logs?

Comment: Actually I am getting the blank screen when I call the popFragment() method from any fragment. I implemented the same logic when I was using v4 Fragments. It works fine with that. But it does not work with AndroidX Fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `NavHostFragment`, so you should never be doing any fragment transactions at all.

The behavior you're trying to achieve is exactly the default behavior when you [connect your NavController to a DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), so you should remove all of that code and follow the documentation.

Comment: I have read this documentation and implemented the same way. Still I am unable to get the desired results. I have updated my whole MainActivity class. I would really appreciate if you can help me in knowing my mistake

Comment: You have not removed enough code. Like I said, you should never be doing any FragmentTransactions when you're using Navigation. That means `ManageFragments` and everything you're doing there needs to be removed. If you remove everything you're doing in `onBackPressed()`, do you get the right behavior (minus the dialog that you want)?

Comment: I removed everything from onBackPressed(). I can navigate back from the top left back sign but I am unable to do so from back button. Even the drawer is not getting closed in back press button. I will edit the post with updated code. Thanks

Comment: I also uploaded mobile_navigation.xml for reference. Thanks

Comment: I was saying removing your override of `onBackPressed()`. Having it do nothing (compared to calling `super.onBackPressed()` will mean the system back will do nothing.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Appreciate that. But I have 1 query then where I should have the dialog fragment logic for exit permission? It should be in mobile_navigation.xml itself?

Comment: Great, I'm glad your original question you asked here is solved. I'd suggest posting a separate question about what you're trying to do with your exit dialog (which is definitely a bit of an anti-pattern in general on Android, FWIW) and include a link here and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Sure will do that.

Comment: I figured out the way to implement dialog. But I have posted new question. Can you please help me with that. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/q/63368961/7948825

Comment: Hello @ianhanniballake I implemented the solution and navigation worked perfectly with child fragments but I wonder I am unable to change the toolbar title and back icon when I navigate to one of the sub fragment after recycler view item click listner

Comment: In this, 'DrawerItem1 -> Frag1 -> Frag2 -> Frag3 -> Frag4' , when I navigate from Frag1 -> Frag2 -> Frag3 I am unable to change the toolbar title and 'back' icon which is suppose to be coming when I go from Frag1 -> Frag2 from the recycler view item click in frag1. Thanks

Comment: Here is the the link for posted question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63406440/7948825. Thank you.