# No adapter attached; skipping layout issue in Recycler Vierw after fragment resume in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

I am implementing recycler view using MVVM architecture. The data is getting populated in recycler view for the first time when fragment is loaded but after coming back to the fragment after back press it does not load list after **resuming** fragment.

Here, is my implementation for Fragment **HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
private RecyclerView rv;
private ProgressBar pb;
private DataAdapter adapter;
private List<DataModel> modelList;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    rv = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_home);
    pb = v.findViewById(R.id.home_pb);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("Home Frag", "onViewCreated: called again after back");

    rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    homeViewModel.getUserMutableLiveData().observe(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), (userListUpdateObserver));
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("HomeFragment", "keyCode: " + keyCode);
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.i("HomeFragment", "keyCode: " + keyCode);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Logout");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Logout?");

                // add the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                getActivity().finish();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                // create and show the alert dialog
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

Observer<List<Category>> userListUpdateObserver = new Observer<List<Category>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(final List<Category> userArrayList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userArrayList.size(); i++) {
            modelList.add(new DataModel(userArrayList.get(i).getTitle(), userArrayList.get(i).getImage(), userArrayList.get(i).getId(), 0));
        }
        adapter = new DataAdapter(getContext(), modelList, new DataAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                homeViewModel.selectedId(modelList.get(position).getId());
                homeViewModel.selectedString(modelList.get(position).getText());
                SubCategoryFragment subCategoryFragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
                ManageFragments.replaceFragment((FragmentActivity) getContext(), subCategoryFragment);
            }
        });
        rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  };
}
```

Here is my ViewModel class **HomeViewModel.java**

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<List<Category>> userLiveData;
public static final MutableLiveData<Integer> selectedItemId = new MutableLiveData<Integer>();
private ApiInterface apiInterface;
public static final MutableLiveData<String> selectedString = new MutableLiveData<String>();

public HomeViewModel() {
    userLiveData = new MutableLiveData<List<Category>>();
    init();
}

public void selectedId(Integer id) {
    selectedItemId.setValue(id);
}

public void selectedString(String name) {
    selectedString.setValue(name);
}

MutableLiveData<List<Category>> getUserMutableLiveData() {
    return userLiveData;
}

private void init() {
    populateList();
}

private void populateList() {
    apiInterface = ApiRequest.createService(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MainCategoryModel> call = apiInterface.getCategory();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MainCategoryModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MainCategoryModel> call, Response<MainCategoryModel> response) {
            userLiveData.setValue(response.body().getData().getCategory());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MainCategoryModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
homeViewModel.getUserMutableLiveData().observe(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), (userListUpdateObserver));
```

You're using the activity as the LifecycleOwner. That is always the wrong LifecycleOwner to use from within `onViewCreated()`. Instead, you need to use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` - the LifecycleOwner associated with the Fragment's view.

```
homeViewModel.getUserMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), 
        userListUpdateObserver);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is, on HomeFragment creation `onViewCreated` is getting called and so its content. On Recycle view, there is no adapter attached in fragment life cycle. You are attaching adapter to your Recycle View in an observer which will be called but **`asynchronously`**. Hence you are getting *`No Adapter Attached: skipping layout error`*.

You only need the observer to update the changes to your adapter's list.
To fix it you need to add adapter on Recycle View in a fragment life cycle such as `onViewCreated` method. Please find the changes in adapter code as follows -

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private CategoryClickListener categoryClickListener;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public interface CategoryClickListener {
        //modify the method according to your requirement
        void onCategoryClick(String id);
    }

    public void setUpCategoryListener(CategoryClickListener categoryClickListener ) {
        this.categoryClickListener = categoryClickListener ;
    }

    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // setup binding of views
    }

    public void setCategoryList(List<Category> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (categoryList!= null)
            return categoryList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //item variable intializer
        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // find views here from item

            //putting click listener to register a click on item
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    categoryClickListener.onCategoryClick(categoryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                }
            });
       }
    }
}
```

Now you can create adapter as -

```
//make adapter as global variable of class; 
CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

//in onViewCreated()
rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext());
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
categoryAdapter.setUpCategoryListener(new CategoryAdapter.CategoryClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCategoryClick(String id) {
        //here you can get the selected item id or any value you require 
        // your fragment transaction as well               
    }
});
```

and under an observer, you can simply use `setCategoryList()` method of CategoryAdapter-

```
Observer<List<Category>> userListUpdateObserver = new Observer<List<Category>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(final List<Category> userArrayList) {
        categoryAdapter.setCategoryList(userArrayList);
    }
};
```

No need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` because that has been taken care `undersetCategoryList()` already.

Even we have take care of `NullPointerException` on userArrayList for adapter under `getItemCount()`

Happy Coding !